# Fetching data from Neo4j using nodejs

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j for the first time with nodejs. I am trying a particular usecase which is " User can search a movie, for eg: Titanic, for recommendation of other similar movies the result must contain movies of the same genre, movies from the same director. " 
When i search for a movie, i am able to get the related nodes like actor, director and genre of the movie. what i want next are the other movies related to this director and genre.

Here 'title' is the name of the movie i am passing in REST API Get method.

````
session.run("MATCH (n:movie{name : $title}) -[:Acted_In|:Directed |: Belong_To]-(r) Return r ",
                        { title: req.params.name }

                        )

        .then(function (data) {

            data.records.forEach(function(record){
            console.log("record._fields[0].properties = ",record._fields[0].properties.name);
            result.push(record._fields[0].properties.name);  
              })
                 console.log(result);

          })
                        ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Cypher query should work for your use case (*"User can search a movie, for eg: Titanic, for recommendation of other similar movies the result must contain movies of the same genre, movies from the same director."*):

```
MATCH (m:movie)
WHERE m.name = $title
MATCH (m)-[:Belong_To]->()<-[:Belong_To]-(x)
WITH m, COLLECT(x) AS xs
MATCH (m)<-[:Directed]-()-[:Directed]->(y)
WITH m, xs, COLLECT(y) AS ys
UNWIND (xs + ys) AS otherMovie
RETURN m, COLLECT(DISTINCT otherMovie) AS recommendations
```

I assume the `Belong_To` relationship points to a genre. I also assume all movies have at least one genre and one director; if that is not true, then the relevant `MATCH` should be an `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

This query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` to separately collect the movies having the same genres (`xs`), and the same directors (`ys`). It then [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/)s the combination of `xs` and `ys` so that it can use `COLLECT(DISTINCT ...)` to get a list of distinct movies.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, it worked just as i wanted. it would be really great if you can explain this a little bit, as i am new in neo4j i am getting a little confused

Comment: I have added some explanatory text to the end.

Comment: Thanks again . :)